# Loop through table not working

Tags: javascript, loops, html-table

I am new to Javascript and am having problems with looping my function.

I am trying to loop through a table and convert the numbers in the second column to a rating in the third column. I have defined a function to convert the numerical rating into text ("Good", "Bad", ...) which I then want to use in my loop. For some reason, the conversion works for the first row but stops at the second.

I couldn't find a answer on here, could anyone help? Thanks

```js
  function convert(number) {
      if (number == 1) {
          return convert = "Bad";
      } else if (number == 2) {
          return convert = "Satisfactory";
      } else if (number == 3) {
          return convert = "Moderate Good";
      } else if (number == 4) {
          return convert = "Good";
      } else {
          return convert = "Excellent";
         }
  }



      var table = document.getElementById("results");
      var rows = table.rows;
      var rowcount = rows.length;

      console.log(rowcount);

      var num = [];
      var txt = [];

      for(var i = 1; i < rowcount ; i++) {
        num[i] = parseInt(table.rows[i].cells.item(1).innerHTML);
        txt[i] = convert( num[i] );
        table.rows[i].cells.item(2).innerHTML = txt[i];
      }
```

```html
  <table id="results">
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Question number</th>
        <th>Assessment value</th>
        <th>Output text</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Q1</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Q2</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Q3</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Q4</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Q5</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: I think it'd be more efficient to use a switch statement too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return` statement usage was incorrect. In your code while returning value, it also changing the `convert` function reference to string "Good", so it was stoping in 2nd time execution. Please check the below corrected version.

```js
  function convert(number) {
      if (number == 1) {
           return "Bad";
      } else if (number == 2) {
          return "Satisfactory";
      } else if (number == 3) {
          return  "Moderate Good";
      } else if (number == 4) {
          return  "Good";
      } else {
          return "Excellent";
      }
  }



      var table = document.getElementById("results");
      var rows = table.rows;
      var rowcount = rows.length;

      console.log(rowcount);

      var num = [];
      var txt = [];

      for(var i = 1; i < rowcount ; i++) {
        num[i] = parseInt(table.rows[i].cells.item(1).innerHTML);
        txt[i] = convert( num[i] );
        table.rows[i].cells.item(2).innerHTML = txt[i];
      }
```

```html
  <table id="results">
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Question number</th>
        <th>Assessment value</th>
        <th>Output text</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Q1</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Q2</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Q3</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Q4</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Q5</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It's your `convert` function assigning return values to a variable rather than just returning them, and the fact that variable has the same name as the function.

When it does `return convert = "whatever"` it destroys itself, as the function itself is really just a variable.

Just use `return "whatever"` instead.